# How to re-transform a date from english to french format

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to transform a script in node.js that displays a date in english format

> April 29

to a french format

> 29 Avril

From extracted data :

> 2019-04-16T13:00:00+02:00

I know that extracted data is already split (function convertParametersDate) and I have to modify it but I can't do it well

Here is the extract of my code :

```
[...]
const timeZone = 'Europe/Kaliningrad';  
const timeZoneOffset = '+02:00';  

[...]

function convertParametersDate(date, time){
  return new Date(Date.parse(date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + time.split('T')[1].split('+')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
}

function addHours(dateObj, hoursToAdd){
  return new Date(new Date(dateObj).setHours(dateObj.getHours() + hoursToAdd));
}

function getLocaleTimeString(dateObj){
  return dateObj.toLocaleTimeString('fr-FR', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false, timeZone: timeZone });
}

function getLocaleDateString(dateObj){
  return dateObj.toLocaleDateString('fr-FR', { day: 'numeric', month: 'long', timeZone: timeZone });
}
```

Comment: you should take a look at momentjs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Date.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

```
const date = new Date('2019-04-16T13:00:00+02:00');
date.toLocaleString('fr-FR', { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })
```

```js
const date = new Date('2019-04-16T13:00:00+02:00');
console.log(
date.toLocaleString('fr-FR', { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })
);
```